# Google Plus login button frame in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, google-plus, social-networking

In my iOS application i am trying login with Google plus account.
I used the SDK of google. I am able to Login succesfully.

But i am facing the issue Google Sign in Button frame coming too small.
I am unable to trace what i am missing. In console iam getting unable to robot-regular.ttf file.

Answer (score 0):

Here im using auto layout on signIn button, this is working code, button is looking wide

```
[self.view setNeedsLayout] ;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

[signInButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[signInButton setStyle:kGPPSignInButtonStyleWide];
[signInButton setColorScheme:kGPPSignInButtonColorSchemeDark];
NSLayoutConstraint *vConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:signInButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint *hConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:signInButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:vConstraint];
[self.view addConstraint:hConstraint];
```